# Difference between Log4J and Logback implementation of %throwable conversion word

Tags: logging, log4j, logback, syslog

My question is very specific to the use of the %throwable or %ex conversion word in Log4J and Logback.

I'll show you my log4.xml and logback.xml contents first (showing the relevant portions only):

LOG4J.XML

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.log4j.Syslog4jAppender"> 
    <param name="Facility" value="USER" />
    <param name="Port" value="514" />
    <param name="SyslogHost" value="syslogserver_ip" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value=" [%thread] %logger %m %throwable" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

LOGBACK.XML

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>syslogserver_ip</syslogHost>
    <port>514</port>
    <facility>USER</facility>
    <suffixPattern>[%thread] %logger %m %ex</suffixPattern>
</appender>
```

After reading the following 2 links I think it's safe to say that the '%ex' conversion word in logback should do the same thing as '%throwable' conversion word in log4j.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

But after using the above 2 configurations I seem to get 2 different results in my syslog server log:

Using LOG4J

```
Dec 15 14:10:01 localhost  [main] SimpleTest Error Trace :  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at com.vksinghh.logback.example.SimpleTest.randomMethod2(SimpleTest.java:28)
        at com.vksinghh.logback.example.SimpleTest.randomMethod1(SimpleTest.java:24)
        at com.vksinghh.logback.example.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:13)
```

Using LOGBACK

```
Dec 15 14:12:09 localhost [main] SimpleTest Error Stack :  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
        at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.randomMethod2(App.java:27)
        at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.randomMethod1(App.java:23)
        at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.main(App.java:13)
Dec 15 14:12:09 localhost  at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.randomMethod2(App.java:27)
Dec 15 14:12:09 localhost  at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.randomMethod1(App.java:23)
Dec 15 14:12:09 localhost  at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.main(App.java:13)
```

This is the code that generates the error message (in both cases it's the same as I use SLF4J)

```
public class App {  
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SimpleTest");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            randomMethod1();
        } catch (Exception ae) {
            logger.error("Error Stack : ", ae);
        }
    }

    private static void randomMethod1() {
        randomMethod2();
    }

    private static void randomMethod2() {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }  
}
```

The LOG4J output is what I want i.e. the exception stacktrace to appear with the log statement. Logback seems to be respecting the %ex conversion word but also ends up sending every line in the stack trace as a new message.

I know using logback with syslog and newlines has some issues, but I would have thought that once the '%ex' conversion word is used to take care of the exception stack trace, that problem with newline will go away.

Is there a difference between the %throwable conversion word of Log4j and %ex conversion word of Logback?

Comment: Looks strange. There is some post process code that the syslog appender is executing - http://pastebin.com/jafGtF24

Comment: Thanks Andy. Your comment gave me an idea that I tried out and it seems to do the trick. The first statement in the postProcess function checks whether the 'throwableExcluded' flag is set or not. If set it returns from the function. So I added the following to my logback configuration: <throwableExcluded>true</throwableExcluded>

Comment: And following is the output in my log now: `Dec 16 09:45:04 localhost [main] SimpleTest Error Stack :  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
        at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.randomMethod2(App.java:27)
        at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.randomMethod1(App.java:23)
        at com.vksinghh.example.TestProjectLogback.App.main(App.java:13)`

Comment: but the java doc says - "Setting throwableExcluded to true causes no Throwable's stack trace data to be sent to the syslog daemon. By default, stack trace data is sent to syslog daemon." Stacktraces won't be sent and that won't be good ?

Comment: Note that I still have the %ex conversion keyword in my suffixPattern. `<suffixPattern>[%thread] %logger %m %ex</suffixPattern>` I think using %ex in the configuration causes the exception stacktrace to be part of the log statement itself and setting the 'throwableExcluded' does not additionally pass every line of the stacktrace to the syslog. Even though this is working I don't think I'm going to use this unless I can understand _how_ this is working.

Comment: thats how it should be :). Update us to on what you find.

Comment: just one information from my side: I guess to add %ex to the suffix is the only way to go in case you would like to have the exception in the same log entry.
Look at http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/net/SyslogAppender.html#172